# Swift: Updating Label / HTTP Request

Tags: swift, xcode, post, httprequest

maybe someone can help to find the answer to my question: 
Iam sending a post request to a backend, which was created with Java and Playframework2.
In my xcode app I can create a user and wheatear or not the user is in the database the backend replies with a statuscode, which I want to display on a label.
The problem is that text/status of the statuscode is always "one behind".

So I start my backend and my xcode app. 
When I click the submit button, which fires the http request with json data to the backend, and the user is created and a statuscode of 200 replies but is not shown on the label.
When i click die submit button again (same person tried to be created) a 409 is responded. 
BUT now the lable shwos the 200 of the request which was send before.

Somebody a clue?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var tfEmail: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var tfUsername: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var tfPW: UITextField!

var ret: String = "app loaded";
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    print("Hello world");




}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func printMessage() -> Void {
    let json = ["email" : self.tfEmail.text!,
                "username" : self.tfUsername.text!,
                "password" : self.tfPW.text!] as [String : Any];

    do {

        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted);

        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:9000/save")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url);

        request.httpMethod = "POST";
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
        request.httpBody = jsonData;

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error -> \(String(describing: error))");
                self.ret = "\(String(describing: error))";
            }
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)");
                if(httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                    self.ret = "success \(httpResponse.statusCode)"
                } else {
                    self.ret = "error \(httpResponse.statusCode)"
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume();
    } catch {
        print(error);
    }

}

@IBAction func postButton(_ sender: Any) {

    printMessage()
    label.text = self.ret;


}
```

}

Comment: Because the call is async, that's why.

Comment: You need to move the `label.text = self.ret` into a dispatchQueue.main.async{} inside of your http task when you get the response code.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you’re setting the label text on the button press, not after getting the value you want. Change your code:

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)");
                if(httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                    self.ret = "success \(httpResponse.statusCode)"
                    doLabelChange()
                } else {
                    self.ret = "error \(httpResponse.statusCode)"
                    doLabelChange()
                }




func doLabelChange() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.label.text = self.ret
        }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help!!